# HP DL360 Gen 9 Power fault LED flashing 8 times

Tags: hp, failed

I have just had a very disconcerting experience.   I have an HP DL360 gen 9 which appears to have spontaneously died.   When power cycled it started OK.   There was nothing obvious in the dmesg log.

I note the server is in a data center, and has, if I recall correctly A/B power, with UPS.   I don't believe any other systems were affected.

Unfortunately the server is remote, so I was relying on remote hands, but I understand that after it stopped responding all lights were flashing lights 8 times, then waiting, then doing this again.  From my reading of https://support.hpe.com/hpesc/public/docDisplay?docId=emr_na-c04444491 this seems to imply a "Power Backplane or storage Backplane" fault.

As per insite from from @MichaelHampton I have managed to pull the log IML log, which states:

0131 Critical       09:47  09/14/2020 09:47  09/14/2020 0001
LOG: Server Critical Fault (Service Information: Runtime Fault, SAS Backplanes,  Storage Backplane 1 (01h))

**Does anyone know the common causes for the above error and how alarmed I should be?**

Comment: What did you see in the iLO event log?

Comment: @MichaelHampton Thank you for this.  I confess to not knowing what I am doing with respect of iLo logs.  I eventually managed to install hp-health tools for CentOS 8, and pulled a log file using the command "hplog -v" after starting the health manager.  I've updated my post with the entry.

Comment: You can configure iLO to send you email alerts, so that you get some notification and hopefully before things get out of hand. You may want to do that. And the log entry sure seems to indicate a problem with the storage backplane. Have you tried replacing it?